# Autohosted App Error

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When trying to deploy my autohosted app I get the following error

```
"localhost:44309" is not the intended audience "ca896394-c64c-46ce-832d-1cf9043274d9/localhost:44309@6afcd346-7cb2-46db-897d-c639dbdf0449"
```

In page load of the default.aspx, i am saving the token in a cookie for reuse purposes. I think it persists after I stop the app.

The app works only when I retract it and clean+redeploy it.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, Microsoft is ending support for Auto-Hosted Apps. http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/

Comment: client requirement so cant comment.

Comment: Does you're client know that in less than six months that App will no longer work? Microsoft is shutting down support for auto-hosted Apps altogether. Any additional time you spend working on this is wasted.

Comment: Probably they didnt! We have mentioned this to them, I think they will ask us to do to a provider hosted instead. Thanks